# How do i fix this mvn install error? Failed to execute rpm-maven-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, rpm-maven-plugin

I'm trying to build a project that I have imported into eclipse. 
I ran mvn clean which ran fine. 
Running mvn install gives me the following error:

```
[WARNING] 'rpmbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[WARNING] operable program or batch file.

 Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.0-beta-2:rpm (default) 
 on project fusion-restful: RPM build execution returned: '1' executing 'cmd.exe /X /C 
 "rpmbuild -bb --buildroot C:\Users\kb60500\fusion-portal\fusion-restful\target\rpm\buildroot 
 --define "_topdir C:\Users\kb60500\fusion-portal\fusion-restful\target\rpm" --target noarch fusion-restful.spec"' -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

`rpmbuild` is a linux specific tool that is not available for windows by default. this tool is executed by the plugin. You can use cygwin to run it on windows but I would think the best results are created using a linux system to execute your build. There is [a blog post](http://oldblog.tim.fyi/blog/2012/11/22/building_rpms_on_windows_with_maven) about this (older but still looks correct).